# Take a desired factor out of a polynomial expression

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm sitting on this exercise:

$f(x) = x^3 + x$, prove that $\lim\limits_{x \to 2}  f(x) = 10$

The solution aims to show that for any $\varepsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that:
$$0 < | x-2| < \delta \implies |f(x)-10| < \varepsilon
$$

To prove that, they open the $|f(x) - 10|$ expression to $|x^3 + x - 10|$ and factorize by $|x-2|$ in this way:
$$
\begin{align}
x^3 + x - 10 &= (x^3 + x - 10)-(2^3 + 2 - 10)\\
& =(x^3 - 2^3) + (x - 2)\\
& = (x-2)(x^2 + 2x + 2^2) + (x-2)\\
& = (x-2)(x^2 + 2x + 5)
\end{align}
$$

I  understand all the process.

**My question is**: How could I think of this alone ? Is there any general pattern that I miss in this demonstration or should I just notice that $f(2) - 10 = 0$ ?

Thanks a lot, hope this is clear.

Comment: You could also perform polynomial division. There is a multitude of different ways of manipulating polynomials in order to extract interesting factors. The trick above is of course rather slick, but it is not the only way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so first, one good thing to know, is that what you are trying to prove is that "f is continuous at 2" which means $f(x) \to_{x \to 2} f(2)$

In particular, it is interesting to see that $f(2) = 10$

In polynomials, everything is simpler when you are searching for a 0 (because a lot of tools you have are for understanding zeroes of polynomials)

This is why you should study $g(x) = f(x) - 10$
This is 0 when $x = 2$

Now you should know, from polynomial factorization, than if $g(2) = 0$, then $(x - 2)$ is a factor of $g$

then a little bit of calculus (such as polynomial divison, or just posing the factorisation an deriving the coefficients), will allow you to find the expression

$g(x) = (x - 2) (x^2 + 2x + 5)$

Answer (score 1):

First thing, polynomials are continuous functions, so that

$$\lim_{x\to x_0}p(x)=p(x_0)$$ always holds.

---

This is confirmed by the fact that

$$p(x)-p(x_0)$$ cancels at $x_0$ so that one can always factor as

$$p(x)-p(x_0)=(x-x_0)\,q(x)$$ for some polynomial $q$. Then in some finite interval $|x-x_0|<\delta_0$, the polynomial $q(x)$ certainly has a bounded absolute value, let $Q_0$, and

$$\delta\le\delta_0\implies|p(x)-p(x_0)|<\delta\,Q_0$$ and one can take

$$\delta<\delta_0,\frac\epsilon Q_0.$$